# Python рандомайзер по спискам и условиям

Tags: python, циклы, list, случайные-числа

Пытаюсь написать рандомайзер, используя комбинации из n по k.
Задача учебная. Цель - рандомно выбирать пару человек (которую сформировал комбинатор). 
Условия: 
1)В один день элемент не может "попасть" в пару с другими элементами более одного раза; 
2)В один месяц комбинации не должны повторяться.

Примерно так у меня выглядят данные:

```
box_names = ['Mr.A','Mr.B','Mr.C','Mr.D','Mr.E','Mr.F','Mr.G','Ms.H','Ms.I','Ms.J','Ms.K','Ms.L','Ms.M','Ms.N']
```

Шаг 1. Выбираю рандомно пару из сформированных комбинатором (pair_for_today),

```
import secrets

pairs = list(combinations(box_names, 2))
pair_for_today = secrets.choice(pairs)
pairs.remove(pair_for_today)
pairs_today_others = pairs
```

Шаг 2. Из Pairs теперь нужно убрать все пары, которые содержат элементы, попавшие в pair_for_today, вытянутую рандомайзером.

Шаг 3. Снова возвращаемся к шагу 1-2 и проделываем до тех пор, пока список не будет пуст.

Как запоминать пары элементов, которые были выбраны для дня 1, чтобы в день 2 такая пара не повторилась? Вносить в списки и сравнивать?

В python я новичок, так решил освоить работу со списками/итерациями. Буду крайне признателен за любые намеки и советы!

Comment: Функция-комбинатор берётся из `itertools`, или своя/из другого модуля?  
И сколько людей выбирается за день?

Comment: Из условия не очень понятно, чем-то выбор очередной пары в один день отличается от выбора на след. день. Но в данной задаче, похоже, нужен не список, а множество, т. е. `set`.

Comment: Функция-комбинатор из itertools. Люди выбираются все, но каждый человек может за день "попасть" в пару только один раз.
Разница дня n и n+1:    в день n+1 не может образоваться такая же пара элементов, как и в день n

Answer (score 1):

Буду надеяться, что правильно понял вашу задачу. В любом случае, это решение может помочь вам.

```py
from itertools import combinations
from random import randint

# функция превращает список ['1', '2', '3', '4', ...] в [('1', '2'), ('3', '4'), ...]
def combine(inp: list) -> list:
    if len(inp) % 2 != 0:
        raise Exception("The dimension of the entered list is odd")
    return[(inp[i], inp[i+1]) for i in range(len(inp)//2)]

box_names = ['Mr.A','Mr.B','Mr.C','Mr.D','Mr.E','Mr.F','Mr.G','Ms.H','Ms.I','Ms.J','Ms.K','Ms.L','Ms.M','Ms.N']
pairs = list(combinations(box_names, 2))

# ищем пары на 3 месяца
for month in range(3):
    pairs_ = pairs.copy()
    monthly = []
    for day in range(30):
        daily = []
        # тут указывается, сколько пар в день нам нужно. В моём примере - две пары каждый день.
        for _ in range(2):
            while 1:
                a = randint(0, len(pairs_)-1)
                if not pairs_[a][0] in daily\
                and not pairs_[a][1] in daily:
                    break
            monthly += [pairs_[a]]
            daily += [pairs_[a][0], pairs_[a][1]]
            pairs_.pop(a)
        print(f'Месяц {month+1}, день {day+1}: {combine(daily)}')
        # если нужно куда-то использовать список пар текущего дня - используем не daily, а combine(daily).
    print(f'\nМесяц {month+1}: {monthly}\n')
```

Результат работы программы:

```
Месяц 1, день 1: [('Ms.H', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.J', 'Mr.E')]
Месяц 1, день 2: [('Mr.G', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Mr.C')]
Месяц 1, день 3: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.H'), ('Ms.H', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 1, день 4: [('Mr.B', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 1, день 5: [('Ms.M', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 1, день 6: [('Mr.C', 'Mr.D'), ('Mr.D', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 1, день 7: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Ms.H')]
Месяц 1, день 8: [('Mr.B', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.G', 'Mr.C')]
Месяц 1, день 9: [('Mr.F', 'Ms.I'), ('Ms.I', 'Mr.E')]
Месяц 1, день 10: [('Ms.I', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.E')]
Месяц 1, день 11: [('Mr.C', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.L')]
Месяц 1, день 12: [('Mr.G', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Ms.I')]
Месяц 1, день 13: [('Ms.J', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 1, день 14: [('Mr.D', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.C')]
Месяц 1, день 15: [('Mr.E', 'Ms.H'), ('Ms.H', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 1, день 16: [('Mr.D', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.F', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 1, день 17: [('Ms.I', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 1, день 18: [('Mr.D', 'Mr.E'), ('Mr.E', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 1, день 19: [('Mr.E', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.K')]
Месяц 1, день 20: [('Mr.C', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 1, день 21: [('Ms.J', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.L', 'Ms.K')]
Месяц 1, день 22: [('Ms.L', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.G')]
Месяц 1, день 23: [('Mr.E', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Ms.H')]
Месяц 1, день 24: [('Ms.H', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Mr.D')]
Месяц 1, день 25: [('Mr.E', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.G', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 1, день 26: [('Mr.D', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Ms.J')]
Месяц 1, день 27: [('Ms.H', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.L', 'Mr.D')]
Месяц 1, день 28: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.L', 'Mr.G')]
Месяц 1, день 29: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.J', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 1, день 30: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.C')]

Месяц 1: [('Ms.H', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.H'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.M', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.C', 'Mr.D'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.B', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.I'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.I', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.C', 'Mr.G'), ('Ms.L', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.I', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.J', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.F', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.D', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.H'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.D', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.I', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.C'), ('Mr.D', 'Mr.E'),('Mr.B', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.E', 'Mr.F'), ('Ms.K', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.B'), ('Ms.J', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.K', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.L', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.I'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.D', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.E', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.H'), ('Mr.D', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.J', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.D', 'Ms.I'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.B', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.H')]

Месяц 2, день 1: [('Mr.B', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.F', 'Mr.E')]
Месяц 2, день 2: [('Mr.C', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 2, день 3: [('Mr.B', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.H')]
Месяц 2, день 4: [('Mr.D', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.F', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 2, день 5: [('Mr.A', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.G', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 2, день 6: [('Ms.K', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.L', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 2, день 7: [('Mr.E', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.C')]
Месяц 2, день 8: [('Mr.A', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.F', 'Mr.C')]
Месяц 2, день 9: [('Ms.J', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.L', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 2, день 10: [('Ms.K', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 2, день 11: [('Mr.B', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.L', 'Ms.I')]
Месяц 2, день 12: [('Ms.J', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 2, день 13: [('Ms.K', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 2, день 14: [('Mr.B', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.C')]
Месяц 2, день 15: [('Mr.D', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.E')]
Месяц 2, день 16: [('Mr.C', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.D')]
Месяц 2, день 17: [('Mr.B', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Ms.I')]
Месяц 2, день 18: [('Mr.E', 'Ms.H'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.L')]
Месяц 2, день 19: [('Mr.G', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.J', 'Mr.E')]
Месяц 2, день 20: [('Mr.E', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.G')]
Месяц 2, день 21: [('Mr.B', 'Mr.C'), ('Mr.C', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 2, день 22: [('Mr.F', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Mr.D')]
Месяц 2, день 23: [('Mr.G', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.C')]
Месяц 2, день 24: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.L', 'Ms.H')]
Месяц 2, день 25: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.E')]
Месяц 2, день 26: [('Mr.C', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.G', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 2, день 27: [('Ms.H', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 2, день 28: [('Mr.G', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Mr.C')]
Месяц 2, день 29: [('Mr.B', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.J', 'Mr.G')]
Месяц 2, день 30: [('Mr.F', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.L')]

Месяц 2: [('Mr.B', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.B', 'Mr.G'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.D', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.C'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.K', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.H'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.I'), ('Ms.J', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.I'), ('Ms.K', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.I'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.I', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.J', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.H'), ('Ms.K', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.E'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.C', 'Mr.E'), ('Mr.D', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.I'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.D', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.I', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.H'),('Ms.L', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.H'), ('Mr.B', 'Mr.C'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.D', 'Mr.E'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.E', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.C', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.H'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.I'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.F', 'Mr.G'), ('Ms.L', 'Ms.N')]

Месяц 3, день 1: [('Mr.E', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.J', 'Ms.L')]
Месяц 3, день 2: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.J', 'Mr.G')]
Месяц 3, день 3: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.I'), ('Ms.I', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 3, день 4: [('Mr.B', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.G', 'Mr.D')]
Месяц 3, день 5: [('Mr.C', 'Mr.D'), ('Mr.D', 'Mr.E')]
Месяц 3, день 6: [('Ms.I', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 3, день 7: [('Ms.L', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 3, день 8: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Ms.K')]
Месяц 3, день 9: [('Mr.A', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.L', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 3, день 10: [('Mr.A', 'Mr.B'), ('Mr.B', 'Mr.G')]
Месяц 3, день 11: [('Ms.M', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 3, день 12: [('Mr.E', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.K')]
Месяц 3, день 13: [('Mr.B', 'Mr.E'), ('Mr.E', 'Mr.D')]
Месяц 3, день 14: [('Mr.D', 'Mr.E'), ('Mr.E', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 3, день 15: [('Mr.D', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.J', 'Mr.E')]
Месяц 3, день 16: [('Mr.F', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.G', 'Mr.C')]
Месяц 3, день 17: [('Mr.C', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.J', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 3, день 18: [('Ms.J', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 3, день 19: [('Mr.A', 'Mr.C'), ('Mr.C', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 3, день 20: [('Mr.B', 'Mr.D'), ('Mr.D', 'Ms.I')]
Месяц 3, день 21: [('Mr.C', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.F')]
Месяц 3, день 22: [('Ms.H', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.K', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 3, день 23: [('Ms.H', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.N', 'Mr.E')]
Месяц 3, день 24: [('Ms.J', 'Ms.M'), ('Ms.M', 'Mr.B')]
Месяц 3, день 25: [('Mr.E', 'Ms.H'), ('Ms.H', 'Mr.G')]
Месяц 3, день 26: [('Mr.C', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.F', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 3, день 27: [('Mr.G', 'Ms.I'), ('Ms.I', 'Ms.K')]
Месяц 3, день 28: [('Mr.C', 'Ms.H'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.J')]
Месяц 3, день 29: [('Mr.C', 'Ms.L'), ('Ms.L', 'Mr.A')]
Месяц 3, день 30: [('Ms.H', 'Ms.I'), ('Ms.I', 'Mr.B')]

Месяц 3: [('Mr.E', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.L', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.I'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.H'), ('Mr.B', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.D', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.C', 'Mr.D'), ('Mr.E', 'Mr.G'), ('Ms.I', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.L', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.N'), ('Ms.K', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.B'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.M', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.H'), ('Mr.E', 'Mr.F'), ('Ms.K', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.B', 'Mr.E'), ('Mr.D', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.D', 'Mr.E'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.H'), ('Mr.D', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.F', 'Mr.G'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.I'), ('Ms.J', 'Ms.N'),('Mr.B', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.C'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.I'), ('Mr.B', 'Mr.D'), ('Ms.I', 'Ms.J'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.F', 'Ms.J'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.E'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.K'), ('Ms.J', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.B', 'Mr.C'), ('Mr.E', 'Ms.H'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.M'), ('Mr.C', 'Mr.F'), ('Mr.A', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.G', 'Ms.I'), ('Ms.K', 'Ms.N'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.H'), ('Ms.J', 'Ms.K'), ('Mr.C', 'Ms.L'), ('Mr.A', 'Mr.D'), ('Ms.H', 'Ms.I'), ('Mr.B', 'Ms.N')]
```

Если задачу понял неправильно - исправьте в комментариях, буду шлифовать ;)

Comment: Благодарю за оптимальный подход! 
Пока разбирался в Вашем решении, пришли идеи, как реализовать задачу, попробую!)) Моя оплошность, немного некорректно сформулировал задачу. За 1 день каждый из элементов должен образовать пару с другим. Но при этом в один день не должен один и тот же элемент встречаться в паре более 1 раза. Например, есть "ABCD". Как вариант в первый день получим пары AD и CB, во второй день уже не можем повторить эти комбинации, остается, например, AB CD. В третий день без вариантов - AC и BD. Элементов ~5000, поэтому шанс, что на след.месяц выпадет та же комбинация,низкая?